# Can an XML file be included in a Visual Studio 2010 project and then referred to in code?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to store an actual XML file in a Visual Studio 2010 project and then refer to it in code?

ie. Can I store an XML file (see fragment below) and then refer to data elements within the XML data?  How can this be done and how would you refer to data elements deep within the XML data using C# or VB code?

If the XML file is added to the project, will it be embedded into the DLL or EXE when compiled?  If not, how can it be embedded into the DLL or EXE?

```
<readReferenceDataResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<readReferenceDataResult xmlns="http://test.website.com/hi/xsd/providermessages/ReadReferenceData/5.6.9">
    <elementReferenceValues>
      <elementName>organisationTypeCode</elementName>
      <referenceSet>
        <referenceCode xmlns="http://test.website.com/hi/xsd/providercore/Elements/5.6.9">1678</referenceCode>
        <referenceDescription xmlns="http://test.website.com/hi/xsd/providercore/Elements/5.6.9">Accupuncture and Eastern Medicine</referenceDescription>
      </referenceSet>
      <referenceSet>
        <referenceCode xmlns="http://test.website.com/hi/xsd/providercore/Elements/5.6.9">6454</referenceCode>
        <referenceDescription xmlns="http://test.website.com/hi/xsd/providercore/Elements/5.6.9">Technical and Laboratory Services</referenceDescription>
      </referenceSet>
      <referenceSet>
        <referenceCode xmlns="http://test.website.com/hi/xsd/providercore/Elements/5.6.9">9782</referenceCode>
        <referenceDescription xmlns="http://test.website.com/hi/xsd/providercore/Elements/5.6.9">Naturopathy and Natural Health</referenceDescription>
      </referenceSet>
      <referenceSet>
        <referenceCode xmlns="http://test.website.com/hi/xsd/providercore/Elements/5.6.9>8557</referenceCode>
        <referenceDescription xmlns="http://test.website.com/hi/xsd/providercore/Elements/5.6.9">Aged Care Services</referenceDescription>
```

Comment: Just to check my understanding of what you're asking - you have an XML Document with data in that you want to read?

Comment: I have an XML document which I would like to include with my app and read from it in code.

Comment: Yes you can do this. If you want read only access, you can embed the xml file as a resource, and then read it as a stream. If you need read/write access, then you will have to maintain the xml as a separate file.

Comment: @series0ne: how do you embed the file as a resource?

Comment: Most simple way: just do prepare a `global variable` containing the `XML`-string.

Comment: @Cylian, simple, but dirty (IMO)

Comment: @CJ7, RIght click on your project, and click properties. Go to the resources tab, and create a resources.resx file, if this does not already exist. From there you can add your xml file as a resource.

Answer (score 3):

Just add [a resource file (`.resx`)](http://picpaste.com/pics/Screenshot_of_a_Resource_File.1367399658.png) to your project if one is not already present. Select File as the resource type and drag your XML file into that and give it a name (if you don't like the automatically generated one).

This will create an embedded resource type which you can then access in code by the automatically generated class representing the resource, so for example if your project is called `Foo` and you add a resource file called `Resources` and add an XML file resource called `MyData`, then you can access that resource at `Foo.Resources.MyData` in code. This will expose the contents of the file as a string, which you can then load into an `XmlDocument` object when you need to by using `XmlDocument.LoadXml`.

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it, the best solution I can think of would be using [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)

You use the `XmlDocument` to hold the XML file you want to read and then you can retrieve the elements/nodes from there.

If you wanted something a bit faster you can also use [`Linq to XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx), which is nice and simple to use.

Finally, if you have memory constraints/don't want to load the whole document into memory to read it every so often you can use [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx). Which allows you to read it directly from file, node by node. It is however forward only, and is a bit tricky to use.